# User's contact message

Tags: javascript, html, contact-form-7

So I am creating this blog and I have a contact button where a user can put his email and message to me.

What is the best way to save the user's data? Should I use a Firebase database or a JSON file? I am a beginner so I am asking here for the best and most common solutions.

Comment: Where will you store the JSON file, then??

Comment: Are you using contact form 7?

Comment: Between Firebase and JSON file, I'm sure that the most safe is Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Contact Form 7` plugin then there is a very good plugin, [Contact Form 7 Database addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/). It will show all user who contacts you in the WordPress backend. It has very good functionality like searching, export, etc.